# show that for an arbitrary continuous r.v. $X, E(X) = - \int_{-\infty}^0F_x(x)dx+\int_0^\infty(1-F_x(x))dx$

Tags: probability-theory, expected-value

The solution defines $X^+ = max(0,X),X^-=min(X,0)$ so $X = X^++X^-,
E(X)= E(X^+)+E(X^-)$

then it states that $X^+ = \int_0^\infty \mathbb{I}_{\{X^+>x\}}$. This part confuses me because my understanding is that X takes individual x from the event space. As $x$ changes between $0$ and $\infty, \mathbb{I}_{\{X^+>x\}}$ decreases. However, after integrating, we can clearly see that $X^+$ is monotonic increasing. Hence, how can $X^+$ be any arbitrary r.v?

from the previous line it is derived $E(X^+) = \int_0^\infty\mathbb{P}(X>x)dx$ (which I can understand in the discrete case)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would you agree that the equation
$$
a = \int_0^\infty \mathbb I_{\{a>x\}}\,dx
$$
holds for all nonnegative real numbers, $a$? Once you believe that, you only need the following fact; if a (deterministic) equation $f(a)=g(a)$ holds for all nonnegative values of $a$, then it also holds for a randomly chosen nonnegative value of $a$ with probability one. Therefore, it is true when you substitute $X^+$ for $a$.

To conclude $E[X^+]=\int_0^\infty P(X^+>\infty)\,dx$, you need to use Fubini's theorem to switch the order of integration and $E$. It is allowed in this case since $\mathbb I_{\{X^+>x\}}$ is always nonnegative (in fact, it is always $0$ or $1$).